Outer product approximation of derivatives of likelihood
Lately, I have been reading Muthén's paper, "Muthén, B. (1984). A general structural equation model with dichotomous, ordered categorical, and continuous latent variable indicators. Psychometrika, 49, 115-132." In the paper, equation (19) mentions that, in large samples, the secondary derivative of the likelihood (Hessian) can be approximated by the product of the first derivatives (gradient). From other sources, it seems like this is related to the outer product approximation (https://www.sherrytowers.com/mle_introduction.pdf). How can we prove that the Hessian can be approximated by the outer product approximation?
Additionally, in the paper, it seems that the sign of the outer product approximation and the Hessian are the same, but shouldn't they be opposite? Also, I am curious why
1/N is not multiplied in the approximation.
In summary, I am wondering why the equation is given as like
$$\partial^2F/\partial\sigma \partial\sigma' = \sum \partial (F(r)/\partial\sigma)( \partial F(r)/\partial\sigma')$$
instead of
$$\partial^2F/\partial\sigma \partial\sigma' = -(1/N)\sum  \partial (F(r)/\partial\sigma)( \partial F(r)/\partial\sigma')$$?

References:

Muthén, B. (1984). A general structural equation model with dichotomous, ordered categorical, and continuous latent variable indicators. Psychometrika, 49, 115-132.(https://www.statmodel.com/wlscv.shtml)
https://www.sherrytowers.com/mle_introduction.pdf


Which equation in the paper are you talking about?

It was a question regarding equations (19) to (21) (The approximaiton of A11, A21, A22). Thanks!

Sorry for the confusion. I was referring to Muthén's paper that I mentioned above. I also included a link to a PDF that explains the concept of the outer product approximation.

I have added the snap. Are the A11, A21, A22 in that paper?

Correct. Thank you for your help!
You can download the paper from (https://www.statmodel.com/wlscv.shtml), fyi.
